# Push an App update to store, But lost Bundle Id, Profile and Certificates

Tags: objective-c, app-store, provisioning-profile, app-id, bundle-identifier

My Company is having an App on the app store. This app was done by an outsourcing company in 2016 and all the contacts with them is closed. Now I need to push an update to this app, But my problem is I don't have the Bundle Id, Certificate, Profile that are used to push the app to store previously.Can I create a new App ID, Distribution Certificate and Profile and push the app to the store with the new Bundle Id. Will that create problem for the users to get the updates. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use same apple id means no problem in upddate

Comment: Do you have access to the ` iTunesConnect` portal, if so you can see all App IDs there, you can create new certificates as well, if you don't have access to it, than first thing to do is to get access granted, if not you are not going to be able to do much...

Comment: As @Ladislav said, if you have access to the itunes connect account that was used to publish the app, you can create a new certificate and provisioning profile to push a new app version.  You will need to use the same bundle ID for the app, or it will be considered a new app.  If you don't have access to the itunes connect account associated with the bundle ID of the app in the store, you will need to get the other company to transfer it to your developer account.

Comment: Thank u so much @ Ladislav @wottle. Yes, I am having access to the 'iTunes Connect'. So as per your comments my understanding is: I can get the AppID and Bundle Id of the pushed app from the 'itunes connect', and I will create a new AppId in the developer account with the same name and based on that AppId create a new provisioning profile , certificate and use them to push to App store. right?. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, you can get the bundle ID (same as the app ID) from either itunes connect, or the Apple Developer site.  There is a section on the developer site for IDs, Certificates and Profiles.  Generate a new distribution certificate there for the App ID of your app.  Then create a new distribution provisioning profile for the certificate you just created.   Use that to sign your new app and it will allow you to upload the app as an update to iTunes Connect.

Comment: @Wottle- I am having an extension (Todays Extension) also in the App. But in the 'itunes connect' I will get the bundle Id of the main app only. I am not sure what bundle Id has been used for the extension in the previous push. Can I use the main app bundle Id as prefix and create a new bundle Id for the Todays Extension and push the App to the app store(ie, say Main App Bundle Id : com.xx.xapp and extension Bundle Id:com.xx.xxapp.todaysExtension. Is it important to use the same bundle Id for the extensions as well in all app store pushes. please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the answer from the comments and my experience after successful updation of the app. Hope it may help someone.

If we lost all the profile, certificate, Bundle Id etc, but if the have the access to the iTunes connect account from where the App was submitted to store, then we can do the following:

1) Go to iTunes connect -> search for your App -> and you will get the Bundle Id of the App from the details 
2) We need the same developer account used to generate the cert, profiles in the previous push. 
       2.1) Developer Account -> Go to App ID -> Find the App Id with the same Bundle Id you found from iTunes.
       2.2) Create a App store distribution certificate
       2.3) Create a distribution provisioning profile by providing the App Id we found out earlier.