# Do we need the same bundle Id for the Extensions to push an Update to the App store

Tags: app-store, today-extension, bundle-identifier

We are having an app in the App store and we need to push a latest update of the app to the store.
     We have lost the Distribution certificate, profiles, AppId with which the app has been pushed to store previously. We only have the 'Bundle Id' of the app from the 'itunes Connect' account.
    The App is having an extension (Today extension is used in the app). My question is as I am having only the bundle Id of the main app(ie, com.xx.xxapp). Can I just create the bundle Id for my extension app with main app bundle id as prefix (ie,  com.xx.xxapp.todayExtention). As I did not know the bundle Id of the extension used in the previous push. Will a mismatch in the bundle Id of the extension used in the old push and new push cause issues for the users to get the update of my app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push an App update to store, But lost Bundle Id, Profile and Certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622879/push-an-app-update-to-store-but-lost-bundle-id-profile-and-certificates)

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. Please help me on the Bundle Id of extension issue. I got clarification from the post mensioned above regarding the bundle Id of the main App. But Still having issue with the bundle Id of the Extension used in the App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the clear answer after submitting an update of my app to the store. Hope this may help anyone.
    To submit an update to an App store App, we need only the Bundle Id of the main app to be same as the bundle id used to push the app to the store initially.
   There will be no problem if the bundle Id of the extension has any difference compared to the previous push. But the Bundle Id of all the extensions should have the prefix as main app bundle Id. ie, If your main app bundle Id is : "com.xxApp" then your extension bundle id should be com.xxApp.MyExtension.